# Retrieving differences between two files - Perforce Java API

Tags: java, api, diff, perforce

I have just written a method for getting a List of differences between two IFileSpec objects, however, I do not know how to actually retrieve the differences from the IFileDiff object.

Here is the method I have written so far,

```
public void getFileDiff(String file1, String file2){

        List<IFileSpec> fileList1 = null;
        List<IFileSpec> fileList2 = null;
        List<IFileDiff> fileDiff = null;
        try{

            fileList1 = getIFileSpecList(file1);
            fileList2 = getIFileSpecList(file2);

            fileDiff = iServer.getFileDiffs(fileList1.get(0), fileList2.get(0), null, DiffType.IGNORE_LINE_ENDINGS,false,true,false);

            for(IFileDiff iFileDiff : fileDiff) {

                System.out.println(iFileDiff.getRevision1() + " ::: " + iFileDiff.getRevision2());

            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

This code happily prints the correct revisions of the files but getting the actual String differences is something I have yet to come across. If anybody knows what to do I would really like to hear from you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to answer this, as far as I remember, there is no way to get the difference of two files using the Perforce Java API. The only way to do it is, Sync out the files to a temporary location and call the OS's built in "diff" command. Capture the output and pipe to your application.